# South - How to force certain migration?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have a migration, 003, that creates a new table, but for some reason, South isn't creating a new table after executing that migration:
I am doing the following command:

```
[kelp@web187 goals]$ python2.7 manage.py migrate main 0003_auto__add_nudge
Running migrations for main:
 - Migrating backwards to just after 0003_auto__add_nudge.
 < main:0006_auto__add_field_nudge_status
```

But I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "main_nudge" does not exist
```

It doesn't exist because the migration 003 is supposed to create it. Why do I get this error?

Comment: Can you show the actual migration. Include the backwards too, because you are executing that one.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It seems like you've faked migration 0006 forward, you should fake it backward too:

```
manage.py migrate --fake yourapp 0005
```

This will set the current migration to 0005.

Apparently, you want to migrate back to 0002:

```
manage.py migrate --fake yourapp 0002
```

And then start over at 0003:

```
manage.py migrate yourapp
```

Comment: Also useful to note the 'zero' keyword works here.  If you delete a table and want South to recreate it, you can `manage.py migrate --fake yourapp zero` and then `manage.py migrate yourapp`

Comment: @IMFletcher Thank you for the tip about the "zero" migration. Note that it also work with Django 1.7 migrations.

Comment: The --fake yourapp zero saved me so much headache!!  It works great with Django1.8.

Comment: "zero"  It works great with Django 1.11, its amazing